# apply trim before copy using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that copies files from azure datalake to azure SQL

- Gets Meta Data of files in a specific path in Datalake
- Loops through the output and copies the file into a database table.

  - file `A.csv` is copied to `dbo.[A]`
  - file `B.csv` is copied to `dbo.[B]`

[image: Get Meta Data and Copy in a For Each Loop]

## Question

- Is there a generic way to define a `trim` on the column values being copied ?

Answer (score 1):

To apply a trim rule across ALL string columns in a dataset in ADF, use Mapping Data Flows with a column pattern.

In a Derived Column, set your matching rule to "type == 'string'".

In the Column Name, keep it the same using $$.

In the Value, set trim ($$,'...')

Reference docs:

Matching Patterns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern

Derived Column: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column

Answer (score 0):

`trim` feature is supported by ADF expressions.([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#trim))

e.g.:

```
trim('!--!wor!ld!', '-!') -> 'wor!ld'
```

Trims a string of leading and trailing characters. If second parameter is unspecified, it trims whitespace. Else it trims any character specified in the second parameter

Comment: I have used expressions in the past, but my question is How do I use this on ALL of the columns of a data set when, the data set schema is unknown (dynamic)